# how can i create multiline editable textview in nativescript?

Tags: user-interface, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

i try beloved code but dos't work in android can't get new line

```
<TextView  style="margin-top: 15px" borderColor="#DEDEDE" borderWidth="1"
 height="100px" hint="Enter Note"  returnKeyType="send" class="input input-border"></TextView>
<Button text="ADD" (tap)="insertNote()"></Button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiline textbox in nativescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013206/multiline-textbox-in-nativescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use height attribute without 'px' unit like this :

```
<TextView style="margin-top: 15px" borderColor="#DEDEDE" borderWidth="1" height="100" hint="Enter Note"  returnKeyType="send" class="input input-border"/>
```

Or give greater value for height in pixel : 200px

Comment: The Text doesn't warp in new line. Is there a solution?